# ArgumentError: Python argument types did not match C++ signature:

Tags: python, c++, boost-python

I am trying to interface my C++ code from Python. So far I have followed the instructions provided by Boost. Namely, those which can be found from here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/tutorial/exposing.html.

**My problem is this:**
I can run my code from the terminal, but I cannot use the class in my Anaconda/Spyder python editor. In Anaconda Spyder editor I get signature error which I do not receive if I run the same code from the terminal. How can I make it work in editor?

Specifically, if I do this:

```
    # test.py
    import greet_ext

    x = "test"
    planet = greet_ext.World(x)
```

I get this error:

```
    ArgumentError: Python argument types in World.__init__(World, str)
    did not match C++ signature:__init__(_object*)
```

**C++ code:**

```
    #include <boost/python.hpp>
    #include <string>

    using namespace boost::python;

    // =========================================================
    struct World
    {
          World( const std::string& msg)
          {
              mMsg   = msg;
          }

          std::string show_message()
          {
              return mMsg;
          }

          std::string mMsg;

          };


    // =========================================================

    BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(greet_ext)
    {
      class_<World>("World",init<const std::string&>())
           .def("show_message", &World::show_message)
           .def("show_number", &World::show_number);
    }
```

Comment: Don't have any experience with it. But I would try use std::string instead of const std::string &.

Comment: I tried this as well. However, I do receive the same ArgumentError when trying to run the code from editor.

Comment: Is your working directory the same as the one that contains the shared library produced?

Comment: What is your python version on Anaconda and on your terminal ? You should add Anaconda et Spyder tags on your question.

Comment: @fedepad my working directory is exactly the same.

Comment: @cromod My Anaconda version is 3.0.0 and Python 2.7

Comment: @JSH could you try in your python call: `planet = greet_ext.World(str(x))` . Does that change something or not?

Comment: Yes, have you tried `planet = greet_ext.World(str(x))`?